# PHP PDO can't run query INSERT INTO with SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

I can't run INSERT INTO and SELECT queries in one statement.

Have problem with this php code:

```
$db = connect_db_marketlist();
if($db != null) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO items (user_id, market_table_id, price, info )"
        ." VALUES ('$id', (SELECT table_id FROM markets WHERE city='$city' AND market='$market'), $price, '$info')";
     echo $sql; // !!! DEBUG !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    try {
        $db->query($sql);
        echo "OKAY: ".$db->lastInsertId();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

And I got error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'market_table_id' cannot be null

Error says SELECT query returns null but when I run $sql statement directly in phpmyadmin, it is working.
This is **echo $sql** output:

> INSERT INTO items (user_id, market_table_id, price, info ) VALUES
>   ('12345678', (SELECT table_id FROM markets WHERE city='ANKARA' AND market='MİGROS'), 22.33, 'TEST_INFO_MİGROS')

What's wrong with me? Maybe it's my db connection:

```
function connect_db_marketlist() {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "marketuserdb";
    $password = "pass1234";
    $conn = null;
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=marketlist", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }   
    return $conn;
}
```

Is it possible to run "INSERT INTO...SELECT..." query with PDO? If yes how, if no why?

P.S: It's working when I enter any integer instead of (SELECT....) query. So no problem with DB connection.

Comment: could you please share output of echo $sql also? That could help us to understand your situation.

Comment: Yes, you can run insert ... select ... in pdo. You run it the same way as any other sql statement.

Comment: PDO has nothing to do here.

Comment: also I see that you are using special Turkish characters. Did you try to add encoding to DSN like (if your tables are in UTF-8)?

("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=marketlist;charset=utf8mb4"

Comment: @tanaydin, yes i have no problem with Turkish char in mysql.

Comment: so you tried charset in your connection string and didn't work?

Comment: This select   (SELECT table_id FROM marketler WHERE city='ANKARA' AND market='MİGROS')  is returning valid market_table_id ??

Comment: @tanaydin, yes it is because of charset=utf8mb4. I add it and its now worikng :) THX.

Comment: converted as answer, I would be happy if you accept it. Thanks.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for guidance with this and other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set connections charset to proper one in DSN like

```
"mysql:host=$servername;dbname=marketlist;charset=utf8mb4"
```

(This is for utf-8, you should set it for your tables encoding)

Comment: Thx. You save my hours :)

Answer (score 0):

the var should be  inside the select

This way

```
"INSERT INTO items (user_id, market_table_id, price, info )"
." SELECT '$id', table_id , $price, '$info' 
         FROM markets WHERE city= '$city' AND market='$market' ;";
```

Comment: I want to get only market_table_id with (SELECT...) statement, not price, info, user.

Comment: Why not  .... if you use this select  you populate the insert column  directly ... in the select you select the content of the var  $id , $price, $info .. this value are not selected from the table  .. but passed ..(injected ) inside the sql statement ..